# How to solve an integral of one over square root of a 4th grade polynomial

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, complex-integration

I would like to solve the following indefinite integral

$$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+gx+1}}dx $$

where a,b,c,g>0 (fyi: I applied g instead of d to the fourth coefficient in order no to confuse it with dx). Let us assume, if we had real values instead of the mentioned coefficients, that we cannot find any roots for the polynomial or rather we cannot simplify the argument of the integral (that would be an easy way to solve it as there are many examples on stack exchange).
Actually, I can obtain an approximated expression for the argument by expanding it according to a Taylor series up to the first order.

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}=1-\frac{u}{2} $$

I noticed though that the final solution is too much approximated especially if then, for instance, I integrate between zero and x>>1. It is not my target to approximate it. I am aware that it is not what it should be properly done.
Your support with the integration procedure would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance. M.

Comment: It depends what you mean by solve. Expressing them as elementary functions, for most coefficients is cannot be done. For $a=b=0$ you can do [Euler's substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution). For $a=0$, $b\neq0$ these are [Elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), which are better studies, by studying their inverse. For $a\neq0$ these are [Hyperelliptic or Abelian integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_integral)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the integral as
$$I=\frac 1{\sqrt a} \int \frac {dx}{\sqrt{(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4)}}$$ and have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5B1%2FSqrt%5B%28x+-+r%5B1%5D%29*%28x+-+r%5B2%5D%29*%28x+-+r%5B3%5D%29*%28x+-+r%5B4%5D%29%5D%2Cx%5D).

If the link is broken, copy/paste for Wolfram Alpha

`Integrate[1/Sqrt[(x - r[1])*(x - r[2])*(x - r[3])*(x - r[4])],x]`

Comment: Hi Claude, thank you for your support. I proceeded as follows: I caculated the roots of the polynomial online and I found two real and two complex roots in this form -a,-b,-c-di,-e-fi where i is the complex numberLet's make a simple example with easy values: if the roots of the 4th grade polynomial are   -3, -5, -3-2i,  -2+4i  means that the new form of the polynomial is (x+3)(x+5)(x+3+2i)(x+2-4i) or do they keep the sign (x-3)(x-5)(x-3-2i)(x-2+4i)? Moreover, can I proceed with the integration as you suggested to me?

Comment: @MarkInt. Stay with the roots as they are if you want to avoid more complex formulae. This is particulary true if, as in our example, the coefficients of the quartic are complex. By the way, if you consider that my answer is valid, may be, you could accept it in order other users knwo it. Cheers :-)